# SQL Server Express and SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-ce, umbraco, sql-server-express

I've just built my first Umbraco site and now I want to hand it over for deployment on a web server. However, I built the site on my local machine using Web Matrix, which uses a SQL Server Compact Edition database, which is represented in a `.sdf` file.

I was a bit uneasy about whether this would be much use to the person I'm passing the site to (they have a number of Umbraco based sites running on this server using SQL Server) - so I installed SQL Server Express and migrated the database from Compact Edition to Express. However (again), I can't seem to find any way of exporting the full database to a file which can then by imported into a database on the web server.

A couple of points I guess - first, is the Compact Edition `.sdf` file actually enough for someone to take and import a database into SQL Server Standard? Failing that, how would I export the database from SQL Server Express to a file which could be used for this purpose?

Thanks in advance - this is my first foray into .net development so I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: if you've got the mssql server management studio installed, you can "detach" a database, which frees up the .mdf/.ldf files which contain the db, make a copy of them, then reattach... the copies can go onto the other server where you attach them and poof... clone of the database.

Comment: You should be able to run a BACKUP DATABASE on the Express instance, and send the .BAK file to restore on Standard edition. Make sure that the Standard Edition instance has a build >= your Express instance (you can't restore a 2008 R2 database on a 2008 instance, for example). Don't use detach/attach. If something goes wrong while the database is detached or detaching, you now have 0 copies of your database. BACKUP is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just give the SQL CE database (.sdf) to the person who manages the web server. The SQL CE database can be run by default on a .NET webserver.
If, for some reason, you want to migrate it to SQL Server, you can do this through Web Matrix (http://www.microsoft.com/web/)

When you have already converted the SQL CE database to SQL Server, you can:

1. make a backup through the SQL Server Management Studio tool and restore the backup on the web server
2. or you can use the SQL Server Management Studio tool to script the database to a .sql file which can be executed on the web server

I prefer the first option.